# Wall collisions in scene kit

Tags: objective-c, scenekit

I'm trying to write a game where a node can move about but is contained by a series of walls- basically a maze game. Just to get the basic thing going I pulled apart Apple's SceneKitVehicle project (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SceneKitVehicle) to just the basic elements and put in a cube (the box node in the code below) instead of the physics vehicle in the original code.

Problem is, I programmatically move the box node until it reaches the wall and it just continues straight through the wall without stopping. Meanwhile, I can put the vehicle code back in and that DOES stop when it reaches the wall.

```
- (void)setupEnvironment:(SCNScene *)scene
{
    //floor
    SCNNode*floor = [SCNNode node];
    floor.geometry = [SCNFloor floor];
    floor.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = @"wood.png";

    SCNPhysicsBody *staticBody = [SCNPhysicsBody staticBody];
    floor.physicsBody = staticBody;
    [[scene rootNode] addChildNode:floor];
}

- (void)moveBox
{
    SCNAction *moveByAction = [SCNAction moveByX:0 y:0 z:-3 duration:0.1];
    SCNAction *repeatAction = [SCNAction repeatActionForever:moveByAction];
    [_boxNode runAction:repeatAction];
}

- (void)setupSceneElements:(SCNScene *)scene
{
    // add walls
    SCNNode *wall = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:[SCNBox boxWithWidth:400 height:100 length:4 chamferRadius:0]];
    wall.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = @"wall.jpg";
    wall.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(24, 2, 1), SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 1, 0));
    wall.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapModeRepeat;
    wall.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapModeMirror;
    wall.geometry.firstMaterial.doubleSided = NO;
    wall.castsShadow = NO;
    wall.geometry.firstMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = YES;

    wall.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 50, -92);
    wall.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody staticBody];
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:wall];
}

- (SCNNode *)setupBox:(SCNScene *)scene
{
    SCNBox *boxgeo = [[SCNBox alloc] init];
    boxgeo.height = 5;
    boxgeo.width = 5;
    boxgeo.length = 5;

    SCNNode *box = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:boxgeo];
    box.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -30);
    boxPosition = box.position;
    box.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI);

    box.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody kinematicBody];

    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:box];

    return box;
}

- (SCNScene *)setupScene
{
    // create a new scene
    SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene scene];

    //global environment
    [self setupEnvironment:scene];

    //add elements
    [self setupSceneElements:scene];

    //setup box
    _boxNode = [self setupBox:scene];

    [self moveBox];

    //create a main camera
    _cameraNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
    _cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    _cameraNode.camera.zFar = 500;
    _cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 60, 50);
    _cameraNode.rotation  = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, -M_PI_4*0.75);
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:_cameraNode];

    return scene;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    SCNView *scnView = (SCNView *) self.view;
    scnView.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];

    SCNScene *scene = [self setupScene];
    scnView.scene = scene;
    scnView.scene.physicsWorld.speed = 4.0;
    scnView.pointOfView = _cameraNode;
    scnView.delegate = self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Any ideas why the box node doesn't get stopped by the wall?

Might the problem be that the box node needs to be propelled by a force like the vehicle is in order for the wall to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is a little tricky. Moving a box AND making it react to physics interaction is not possible in the way to envision it with a `kinematicBody`.

You can keep that, but you will need to fake the collision yourself based on position/bounding boxes, or listen for intersections in the Physics World.

You could also change to a dynamic body, that interacts with other dynamics objects. However, in the `moveBox` function, you are using `SCNAction`s to move the Box. If you are using a `dynamicBody`, it *cannot* be moved that way. You'll have to use [forces](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNPhysicsBody/kinematicBody).

The last option is simply to use a `SCNConstraint`. Not the prettiest, but if your wall doesn't move it will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions. I like the idea of letting the physics world deal with everything but then to move to a specific position I'd have to calculate the precise force required to move the box each time (which could be highly complex if I ever decide to make the floor uneven I suspect).

Comment: Looking into the SCNConstraint approach, would this be viable for a maze where there's many different walls? (Obviously there's just the one in my code above but this is just a test case to start working from)

Comment: Here's a quick question: are you simply trying to move a cube, in one of four directions until it reaches a wall? If you explain your end goal I can help you find the best way to achieve it.

Comment: Nothing quite so simple I'm afraid. I'd like to be able to tap somewhere in the scene and have the cube move as close to that as it can before hitting a wall. The cube isn't limited to moving in just one of four directions as it can move at any angle (in two dimensions on a plane at least) until it hits a wall. Sorry, I wasn't expecting you to do all the heavy lifting here- I just need a nudge in the right direction. It currently sounds like I'm going to have to do intersection checks and work out the logic of where to stop and position the cube if a wall is in the way.

Comment: No problem! I'll think it through and update my answer.

Comment: I haven't yet solved this but I'll keep digging. Meantime I'll flag your answer as correct since it's definitely given me a few options to look into further.